# Get all media from wp-json/wp/v2/media

Tags: media, json

I'm struggling with a strange issue. I was pretty sure that I can use such a pattern to collect all media:

```
def get_all(url):
    all_results = []
    page = 1
    posts_url = "{0}?per_page={1}&page={2}&order=asc".format(url, 10, page)
    r = requests.get(posts_url)
    page_results = r.json()
    all_results.extend(page_results)
    while len(page_results) == 10:
        page += 1
        posts_url = "{0}?per_page={1}&page={2}&order=asc".format(url, 10, page)
        r = requests.get(posts_url)
        page_results = r.json()
        all_results.extend(page_results)

    return all_result

def get_all_media(url):
    return get_all("{0}wp/v2/media".format(url)
```

Unfortunately the:

`wp-json/wp/v2/media?per_page=10&page=6&order=asc`

call returns only 8 elements, however there are pages number:
7 - 8 elements,
8 - 1 element

Is it correct or my Wordpress instance is malfunctioning?

//edit

Thanks to @SallyCJ I'm now familiar with X-WP-Total and X-WP-TotalPages headers.

However, I'm still not convinced if this instance works correctly. The X-WP-TotalPages contains a correct value (8), but X-WP-Total is equal 71.

- 6 pages with 10 elements = 60 elements
- 2 pages with 8 elements = 16
- elements 1 page with 1 element = 1 element

Sum: 77 elements

Which is not equal to the X-WP-Total header.

Comment: You've used the correct [pagination parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/), and you could confirm whether there's a page 7, 8, etc. by checking the value of the **`X-WP-TotalPages` *header***.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you, the X-WP-TotalPages indeed will do the trick. However - I'm not sure how X-WP-Total works and I'm still afraid that something is wrong. Could you check my edit?

Comment: If `X-WP-Total` was 71, then if your code requested for 10 items **per page**, there would indeed be a total of 8 pages, where the first 70 items would be available from pages 1 to 7, whereas the 71th would be on page 8. I.e. In PHP, the Math calculation is `ceil( 71 / 10 )` = 8. So if your array contained 77 total items instead, or that certain pages (except the last) returned less items than specified via the `per_page` parameter, then I don't know why. Try asking on Stack Overflow for assistance with the specific language your code is written in.

Comment: @SallyCJ it is not a matter of language. I achieve the same result by visiting the "wp/v2/media" endpoint with firefox.

Comment: "*by visiting the "wp/v2/media" endpoint*" - what exactly are the URL parameters you used? Edit your post/question and include all the details that can help others reproduce the issue. But you can try switching to a default/core theme like Twenty Twenty-One and see if the same issue persists. You can also try deactivating all plugins and see if doing so helps.